# .Net Core, Eventhub: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-eventhub

I'm developing producer of the EventHub. Locally it works fine, after deploying to our test environment - I receive error  "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

Docker image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1

Code used:

```
await using (var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString))
                {
                    var eventData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message)));

                    var batch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();
                    batch.TryAdd(eventData);
                    await producerClient.SendAsync(batch);
                }
```

StackTrace :

```
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\n  
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()\n 
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)\n 
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)\n   a
t System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\n 
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__64_2(IAsyncResult iar)\n 
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.TaskHelpers.EndAsyncResult(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\n 
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.StreamExtensions.EndAuthenticateAsClient(SslStream sslStream, IAsyncResult asyncResult)\n
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransport.HandleOpenComplete(IAsyncResult result, Boolean syncComplete)\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n 
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.ExceptionDispatcher.Throw(Exception exception)\n
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)\n  
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpObject.OpenAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)\n  
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpObject.EndOpen(IAsyncResult result)\n  
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransportInitiator.HandleTransportOpened(IAsyncResult result)\n
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransportInitiator.OnTransportOpened(IAsyncResult result)\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown    ---\n 
at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.CreateAndOpenConnectionAsync(Version amqpVersion, Uri serviceEndpoint, EventHubsTransportType transportType, IWebProxy proxy, String scopeIdentifier, TimeSpan timeout)\n
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)\n 
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)\n 
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)\n  
at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.OpenProducerLinkAsync(String partitionId, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.CreateLinkAndEnsureProducerStateAsync(String partitionId, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)\n
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)\n 
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)\n  
at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.CreateBatchAsync(CreateBatchOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n  
at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.CreateBatchAsync(CreateBatchOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n  
at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer.EventHubProducerClient.CreateBatchAsync(CreateBatchOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer.EventHubProducerClient.CreateBatchAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n",
```

Additional Data:
Have tried to add this as suggested in similar topic, but didn't help

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

Comment: This definitely looks like the service rejecting the connection, though I'm not sure why. 
  Would you mind sharing how the producer was created?   I'd like to understand whether the transport is set for TCP or WebSockets.

Comment: producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString), so I expect default tcp connection was used

Comment: Thank you.   Your assumption is correct; TCP is used as the default transport.  Unfortunately, as this appears to be occurring within the service, there's not much insight that I can provide from the client perspective.   I'll follow up with the Event Hubs service team and ask that they assist.

Comment: Have you enabled IP filters or VNET by any chance?

Comment: There are no ip filtering or vnet configuration in azure portal account, it's configuration is close to the default. 
Previously I had problem with our company firewall, but at this stage I got System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (this is fixed now).

Comment: do you think sharing snapshot will help us to understand the issue in detail?

Comment: @NadeemTaj Do you mean snapshot of Azure configuration ?

Comment: yes, also project deployment window and deployment server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was important information which wasn't mentioned - services was deployed in docker via Kubernetes.

This error was related to our internal company firewall settings.